# MATLAB: Inputting enough arguments, still getting a "not enough input arguments" error

Tags: matlab, constructor, arguments

I'm having problems with the class constructor for my `CoaxLine` class. I pass it all the arguments it needs, but when I create an object in another program, I get the error:

```
Error using length Not enough input arguments.

Error in CoaxLine (line 23) function obj = CoaxLine(pow,len,h,freq,x1,x2,y1,y2,dir,split)

Error in Test2 (line 38) coax1 = CoaxLine(3.9,100,4.75,1800,10,110,10,10,0,1);
```

I got this same error with length even when I removed all the argument requirements for the constructor, and created the object with no inputs. This is my first time building a class in MATLAB, so it is likely that I missed something silly. I appreciate the help.

Here is the code for `CoaxLine`:

```
classdef CoaxLine
    %UNTITLED2 Summary of this class goes here
    %   Detailed explanation goes here

    properties
        %Default values
        PA = 3.9;
        orientation = 0; %0 for East-West, 1 for North-South
        splitter = 1; %0 for left side, 1 for right side
        length = 90;
        frequency = 1800; %in MHz
        height = 4.75;
        Ce = 8.77; %Hardcoded for now
        Lint = .13; %Hardcoded
        nearFieldLength = 2*(length^2)/((3.0*10^8)/(frequency*10^6));
        X1 = 10; %Will be points in the simulation axis
        X2 = 110;
        Y1 = 10;
        Y2 = 10;
        %loss = 10;
    end

    methods
        function obj = CoaxLine(pow,len,h,freq,x1,x2,y1,y2,dir,split)
            %if nargin > 0
            obj.PA = pow;
            obj.length = len;
            obj.height = h;
            obj.frequency = freq;
            obj.X1 = x1;
            obj.X2 = x2;
            obj.Y1 = y1;
            obj.Y2 = y2;
            obj.orientation = dir;
            obj.splitter = split;
            %end
        end

        function r = contribution(px,py)
            if(obj.orientation == 0)
                if(obj.splitter)
                    if(abs(py - obj.Y1) <= obj.nearFieldLength && px > obj.X1 && px < obj.X2)
                        H = abs(py - obj.Y1);
                        x = px - obj.X1;
                        r = NearFieldPropagation(obj.PA,obj.length,obj.frequency,H,obj.height,obj.Ce,obj.Lint,x);
                    end
                else
                    if(abs(py - obj.Y1) <= obj.nearFieldLength && px < obj.X1 && px > obj.X2)
                        H = abs(py - obj.Y1);
                        x = obj.X1 - px;
                        r = NearFieldPropagation(obj.PA,obj.length,obj.frequency,H,obj.height,obj.Ce,obj.Lint,x);
                    end
                end

                %else

            end
        end
    end
end
```

Comment: I'm very sorry! Whoever posted the answer with the edited code, and advised me to change my length variable and the implementation of nearFieldLength was correct. I meant to write a thank you note on Thursday but my days have been quite busy lately. Thank you so much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

The error stems from this line:

```
    nearFieldLength = 2*(length^2)/((3.0*10^8)/(frequency*10^6));
```

MATLAB thinks that you're trying to call the function `length`. That requires an argument whose length will be returned.

The use of `frequency` will give you headaches too. To properly handle this kind of `properties` you should declare your `nearFieldLength` as `Dependent`: http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_oop/access-methods-for-dependent-properties.html and then write a getter for it that will calculate its value on the fly.

Also, as [excaza](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2748311/excaza) noted, you'll have further errors because you don't declare `obj` as argument in `contribution`.

This is my idea on how the code should look like:

```
classdef CoaxLine

        properties
                PA          = 3.9;
                orientation = 0;
                splitter    = 1;
                length      = 90;
                frequency   = 1800;
                height      = 4.75;
                Lint        = .13;
                X1 = 10;
                X2 = 110;
                Y1 = 10;
                Y2 = 10;
        end;

        properties(Dependent, SetAccess=private)
                Ce;
                nearFieldLength;
        end;

        methods
                %//Constructor
                function obj = CoaxLine(pow,len,h,freq,x1,x2,y1,y2,dir,split)
                        if nargin > 0
                                obj.PA          = pow;
                                obj.length      = len;
                                obj.height      = h;
                                obj.frequency   = freq;
                                obj.X1          = x1;
                                obj.X2          = x2;
                                obj.Y1          = y1;
                                obj.Y2          = y2;
                                obj.orientation = dir;
                                obj.splitter    = split;
                        end;
                end;


                %//Getters for dependent properties
                function val = get.Ce(obj)  %#ok<MANU>
                        val = 8.77;  %//this can be changed later
                end;

                function val = get.nearFieldLength(obj)
                        val =  2*(obj.length^2)/(3E8/(obj.frequency*1E6));
                end;


                %//Normal methods
                function r = contribution(obj, px, py)
                        r = []; % some default value
                        if obj.orientation == 0
                                if obj.splitter
                                        if abs(py - obj.Y1) <= obj.nearFieldLength ...
                                        && px > obj.X1 ...
                                        && px < obj.X2
                                                H = abs(py - obj.Y1);
                                                x = px - obj.X1;
                                                r = NearFieldPropagation(obj.PA,obj.length,obj.frequency,H,obj.height,obj.Ce,obj.Lint,x);
                                        end;
                                else
                                        if abs(py - obj.Y1) <= obj.nearFieldLength ...
                                        && px < obj.X1 ...
                                        && px > obj.X2
                                                H = abs(py - obj.Y1);
                                                x = px - obj.X1;
                                                r = NearFieldPropagation(obj.PA,obj.length,obj.frequency,H,obj.height,obj.Ce,obj.Lint,x);
                                        end;
                                end;
                        end;
                end;
        end;
end
```